# ffmpeg doesn't set the audio language

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a VOB file of a DVD I wish to back up. It contains one video stream, and several audio streams. I have identified that stream 4 is English, 5 is French, 6 is Spanish.

I have done the following to set the track languages:

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.vob \
  -vf yadif -map 0:0 -codec:v libx265 -crf 22 \
  -codec:s copy \
  -map 0:4 -metadata:s:a:4 language=eng \
  -map 0:5 -metadata:s:a:5 language=fra \
  -map 0:6 -metadata:s:a:6 language=spa \
  -ss 600 \
  xxx.mkv
```

The input and mapping is the following:

```
Input #0, mpeg, from 'xxx.vob':
  Duration: 00:40:48.96, start: 0.280633, bitrate: 16817 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 33 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9800000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1[0x23]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:2[0x24]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:3[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:6[0x83]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:7[0x84]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:2 (ac3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:3 (ac3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
```

As you can see, no language.

Output doesn't indicate the language despite my `-metadata` specifying it:

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'xxx.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
    Stream #0:2: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
    Stream #0:3: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
```

When opened in VLC, the audio tracks are called "Track 1", "Track 2", etc:

[image: VLC screenshot of audio tracks]

How come ffmpeg didn't set the language to what I had put? I checked and they're ISO639-2

I skipped 10 min to get where people talk to confirm the language.

This is lsdvd output for audio tracks:

```
$ lsdvd -a -t 20
Disc Title: xxx
Title: 20, Length: 01:28:18.633 Chapters: 37, Cells: 38, Audio streams: 05, Subpictures: 05
        Audio: 1, Language: en - English, Format: ac3, Frequency: 48000, Quantization: drc, Channels: 6, AP: 0, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x80
        Audio: 2, Language: en - English, Format: ac3, Frequency: 48000, Quantization: drc, Channels: 6, AP: 0, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x81
        Audio: 3, Language: fr - Francais, Format: ac3, Frequency: 48000, Quantization: drc, Channels: 6, AP: 0, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x82
        Audio: 4, Language: es - Espanol, Format: ac3, Frequency: 48000, Quantization: drc, Channels: 6, AP: 0, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x83
        Audio: 5, Language: en - English, Format: ac3, Frequency: 48000, Quantization: drc, Channels: 2, AP: 0, Content: Comments1, Stream id: 0x84
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK turns out the metadata syntax applies to the output stream ID, not input:

```
-map 0:<source ID> -metadata:s:a:<output ID> language=xxx
```

Proof:

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.vob \
  -vf yadif -map 0:0 -codec:v libx265 -crf 22 \
  -codec:s copy \
  -map 0:4 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng \
  -map 0:5 -metadata:s:a:1 language=fre \
  -map 0:6 -metadata:s:a:2 language=spa \
  -ss 600 \
  xxx.mkv
```

Result

```
Input #0, mpeg, from 'xxx.vob':
  Duration: 00:40:48.96, start: 0.280633, bitrate: 16817 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 33 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9800000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1[0x23]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:2[0x24]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:3[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:6[0x83]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:7[0x84]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
[...]
Output #0, matroska, to 'xxx.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
    Stream #0:2(fre): Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
    Stream #0:3(spa): Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
```

And in the player

[image: VLC screenshot]